# SAS filter date for the last three months from the start of the third month

Tags: sas, macros, datefilter

I would like to filter my dataset to the last three months starting from the first of the month in SAS.

I have the following for the yesterday and the last 15 days with macro:

```
DATA _NULL_;
    yesterday=put(INTNX('day',&today,-1),DATE11.);
    twoweeksago=put(INTNX('day',&today,-15),DATE11.);
    /*threemonths = put(intnx('month', &today, -3, 'same')*/
    call symput('rpt_dt',yesterday);
    call symput('rpt_dt2',twoweeksago);
    /*call symput('rpt_3',threemonths);*/
RUN;
```

I tried modifying the yesterday and twoweeks ago lines, as you can see from the commented out lines, but this only works three months from today, which means I am filtering all the way to June 23rd and not the June 1st.

For now the work around is to be explicit about how many days since June 1st, but I am thinking there could be a way to code what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
threemonths = put(intnx('month', &today, -3, 'same')
```

That's close!  Do you happen to know what the 'same' parameter does?  It's an alignment specifier.  See the [intnx documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm) for the other options - `beginning`, `middle`, `end` (or their initial letter).

```
threemonths = put(intnx('month', &today, -3, 'B')
```

That will start on the 1st of the month 3 months ago.